# Thematic base maps in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, online

Does MapInfo have thematic base maps like the templates you get with ArcGIS data and maps?

Answer (score 2):

MapInfo does have thematic maps, I'm not sure whether these are the same as the ArcGIS offering however.

You can apply a theme to pretty much any vector data based on attributes or a user expression. Open some data in a map window, go to the Map option on the menu bar and select Create thematic map. From there you can select the layer and attribute/expression information you want to use to create the theme as well as what type of theme to use (e.g. ranges, individual values, graduated, grid...). Once all options set and OK is clicked a new thematic layer based on your selected options should be added to the existing map window.